# Inconsistent shapes between outputs and targets

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have the following code to train a transformer-based model (huggingface) for a multi-head regression task (I call it multi-head because the model predicts multiple output scores, not only one).

```
# select device
device = 'cuda' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print("DEVICE: ", device)
MAX_LEN = 512
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 8
VALID_BATCH_SIZE = 8
TRAIN_EPOCHS = 1
TEST_EPOCHS = 1
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-05
REG_DROPOUT = 0.1
DISPLAY_STEP_THRESHOLD = 100
MODEL_NAME_CHECKPOINT = 'bert-base-uncased'
MODEL_FOLDER = 'autotune_multihead_regression_model'
# *************** DATA *********************
# load data
train_data = pd.read_csv(f"derived_data/traindev_fold{args.fold}.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv(f"derived_data/test_fold{args.fold}.csv")

train_data['labels'] = train_data[train_data.columns[2:]].values.tolist()
test_data['labels'] = test_data[test_data.columns[2:]].values.tolist()

print("train data shape: ", train_data.shape)
print("test data shape: ", test_data.shape)

# make datasets
train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(train_data)
test_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(test_data)

dataset = DatasetDict({
    'train': train_dataset,
    'test': test_dataset
})

# initialize tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_CHECKPOINT)


def preprocess_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["full_text"], truncation=True, padding="max_length")


# apply the preprocessing on the entire dataset
encoded_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)


# ******************** FINETUNING ********************#

class BERTClass(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BERTClass, self).__init__()
        self.l0 = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME_CHECKPOINT)
        self.l1 = torch.nn.Linear(768, 6)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels):
        """"Override the function forward. Note that keys not appearing here will be removed by trainer.
        It does not matter if trainer is not used.
        """
        # _, output_0 = self.l0(ids, attention_mask=mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, return_dict=False)
        _, output_0 = self.l0(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, return_dict=False)
        output = self.l1(output_0)
        return output


def model_init():
    model = BERTClass()
    return model


args = TrainingArguments(
    MODEL_FOLDER,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=VALID_BATCH_SIZE,
    num_train_epochs=5,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    # this is an advantage in the sense that the last model is not necessarily the best one.
    metric_for_best_model="mean_rmse",
    logging_strategy="steps",
    logging_steps=100,
    push_to_hub=False
)


def mean_rmse(outputs, targets):
    """"
    :param
        outputs: 2D list
        targets: 2D list
    :returns
        a scalar real number
    """
    delta = outputs - targets
    delta = torch.sqrt((delta ** 2).mean(axis=0))
    return delta.mean()


def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    return {"mean_rmse": mean_rmse(predictions, labels)}


class RegressionTrainer(Trainer):
    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        labels = inputs.get("labels")
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()(outputs.squeeze(), labels.squeeze())
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss

temp_dataset = encoded_dataset["train"].select(range(100))

trainer = RegressionTrainer(
    model_init(),
    args,
    train_dataset=encoded_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=temp_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)

trainer.train()
```

In the code, I use a customized model because I want to have the flexibility of the head. Also, I use Trainer to train the model because I want to use `hyperparameter_search`.
The target (`labels`) of the dataset is a (row) vector of 6 variables.
Now the training seems going well when I can see the loss decreasing.
However, the code crashes when it starts the evaluation.
In the code above, I use part of the training set for evaluation, and it throws:

```
***** Running Evaluation *****
  Num examples = 100
  Batch size = 8
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 13/13 [00:00<00:00, 13.35it/s]
  File "autotune_multiregression_head_bert.py", line 152, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1504, in train
    ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1834, in _inner_training_loop
    self._maybe_log_save_evaluate(tr_loss, model, trial, epoch, ignore_keys_for_eval)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2052, in _maybe_log_save_evaluate
    metrics = self.evaluate(ignore_keys=ignore_keys_for_eval)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2781, in evaluate
    metric_key_prefix=metric_key_prefix,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 3059, in evaluation_loop
    metrics = self.compute_metrics(EvalPrediction(predictions=all_preds, label_ids=all_labels))
  File "autotune_multiregression_head_bert.py", line 130, in compute_metrics
    return {"mcrmse": mcrmse_fn(predictions, labels)}
  File "autotune_multiregression_head_bert.py", line 123, in mcrmse_fn
    delta = outputs - targets
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (87,6) (100,6)
 20%|
```

I got the same error when evaluating on the test set. I assume some examples got failed when evaluating and are not added to the final result, hence the final shape of `outputs` is not consistent with `targets`? (I debugged and see that `outputs` has 87 examples while `targets` has 100).
What has gone wrong?

Comment: From what i can see its a shape inconsistency:
one has a batch of 87, another has 100, you have to make sure both have a batch of 100

Comment: The batching is done by the trainer, and I am not sure why it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the shape issue. I was able to compute the metrics for the same model. The returns from the models may be different, you can try to do this

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    return {"mean_rmse": mean_rmse(predictions, labels)}
```

Or try this

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits = eval_pred.predictions[0]
    predictions, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    return {"mean_rmse": mean_rmse(predictions, labels)}
```

Not sure about the answer but had something similar problem and it solved it.